# Difficulties in proving the area-law conjecture in higher dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, entropy, mathematical-physics, quantum-entanglement

A very famous and important open conjecture in condensed matter physics is the area law of entanglement entropy, which claims that in a locally-interacting quantum many body system, if the ground state is unique and has a  spectral gap $\Delta$ non-vanishing in the thermodynamic limit, the bipartite entanglement entropy of a subsystem is proportional to its surface area $A$ instead of its volume $V$. [arXiv:0808.3773](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3773) gives a review on related issues.

In 1D, the conjecture was rigorously proved by Hastings in  [arXiv:0705.2024](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2024) and a better bound was obtained by Arad et al. in [arXiv:1301.1162](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1162). But to my knowledge, the status of the conjecture in dimension $d>1$ still remains open. What are the difficulties in proving it in higher dimension? Are there known counterexamples?